# Is mathematics free of emotion?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

I was planning to ask this on Math SE, but I decided Philosophy SE is more suited to this type of question. Is mathematics free of emotion? Certainly, solving mathematical problems and proving mathematical theorems can elicit emotions in human beings, but that is not what I am talking about. I don't mean the human discipline of doing mathematics, I mean the collection of mathematical objects themselves. I doubt that, for instance, numbers, functions, or vector spaces feel emotions. So, is mathematics itself emotionless?

Comment: "Limit inferior" hates being called that.

Comment: It would be a category error to say mathematical objects have such a property, unless you are Tegmark or another mathematical universe proponent where all objects really are (a very restricted and idiosyncratic form of) mathematical objects. Saying they do would be like saying a "cucumber is really a Ferrari" in the words of David Albert (https://youtu.be/VN19VOMHxkk?t=5112) to the vast majority of philosophers. So "yes", unless you want to pay a very very high price in order that emotion having things are purely mathematical objects.

Comment: According to yourself, mathematics = collection of mathematical objects and mathematical objects do not have emotions. Can't you put 2 and 2 together? Just in case, most physical objects do not have emotions either, so crystallography and astrophysics are also free of emotion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question suggests the possibility that mathematical objects might experience emotions. But it is not possible under any circumstances at all - not logically possible. So mathematical objects are not subject to emotions and consequently not free of emotions (in the sense that a human being might be free of them at some times and in some circumstances). You are right that they can provoke them, but as you recognize, that's a different issue.